# project tango usage in an oem product

Tags: google-project-tango

We are trying to use Project Tango in our prototype/future product. We are open to use either Asus or Lenovo.

Does anyone know what the licensing is? Or is it now in the hands of Asus/Lenovo?

Comment: Fyi, language-lawyer is about language specification questions, not about licensing issues.

Comment: @Barry, thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would need to contact google as tango is their product and lenovo/asus license it from google. FYI, the future of tango is somewhat up in the air currently as google has said little about the program and have seriously reduced the updates to the handsets and code. you would be better off if you tried ARCore by google which seems to be the way forward with AR as far a google is concerned.